# OneToOne relation inside Json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa, spring-data

I created an SecretData object whitch I am sending to frontend:

```
package pl.portal.randkowy.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;

import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity(name = "SecretData")
@Table(
        name = "secret_data",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "secret_data_id_unique",
                        columnNames = "id")
        }
)
public class SecretData {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "secret_data_sequence",
            sequenceName = "secret_data_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "secret_data_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false,
            unique = true
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "login",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String login;

    @Column(
            name = "password",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String password;

    @Column(
            name = "role",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String role;

    @Column(
            name = "private_email",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String privateEmail;

    //1-kierunkowa relacja
    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER, //domyślne
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "person_id", //nazwa kolumny w tabeli bazy danych
            referencedColumnName = "id", //nazwa pola z klasy Person po którym idzie relacja
            nullable = true,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "person_secret_data_fk"
            )
    )
    @JsonBackReference
    private Person person;

    public SecretData() {
    }

    public SecretData(String login, String password, String role, String privateEmail) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.privateEmail = privateEmail;
    }

    public SecretData(String login, String password, String role, String privateEmail, Person person) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.privateEmail = privateEmail;
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getPrivateEmail() {
        return privateEmail;
    }

    public void setPrivateEmail(String privateEmail) {
        this.privateEmail = privateEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SecretData{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", login='" + login + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                ", privateEmail='" + privateEmail + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

It has OneToOne relation to Person

```
package pl.portal.randkowy.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(
        name = "persons",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(
                        name = "person_email_unique",
                        columnNames = "email")
        }
)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "person_sequence",
            sequenceName = "person_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = SEQUENCE,
            generator = "person_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            name = "id",
            updatable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
            name = "name",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String name;
    @Column(
            name = "last_name",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String lastName;
    @Column(
            name = "date_of_birth",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "DATE"
    )
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @Column(
            name = "sex",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String sex;
    @Column(
            name = "sexual_orientation",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String sexualOrientation;
    @Column(
            name = "marital_status",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String maritalStatus;
    @Column(
            name = "province",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String province;
    @Column(
            name = "city",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String city;
    @Column(
            name = "self_description",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String selfDescription;
    @Column(
            name = "life_motto",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String lifeMotto;
    @Column(
            name = "thought_of_the_day",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String thoughtOfTheDay;
    @Column(
            name = "photo",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String photo;
    @Column(
            name = "profession",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String profession;
    @Column(
            name = "education",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String education;
    @Column(
            name = "email",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String email;

    //trzeba dodać, żeby z relacji 1-kierunkowej zrobić relacje 2-kierunkową
    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "person",
            orphanRemoval = false,
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE}
    ) //pole po którym idzie relacja z klasy SecretData
    @JsonManagedReference
    private SecretData secretData;

    //trzeba dodać, żeby z relacji 1-kierunkowej zrobić relacje 2-kierunkową
    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "person",
            orphanRemoval = false,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    ) //pole po którym idzie relacja z klasy Preference
    private Preference preference;


    //jeśli ma być 2-kierunkowa to też tutaj trzeba dodać poniższy wpis i metody poniżej
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "person",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY //domyślna wartość
    )
    private List<Proposition> propositions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "sender",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY //domyślna wartość
    )
    private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();


    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_interest",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "person_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "person_id_fk")
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "interest_id",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "interest_id_fk")
            )
    )
    private List<Interest> interests = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, String sex, String sexualOrientation, String maritalStatus, String province, String city, String selfDescription, String lifeMotto, String thoughtOfTheDay, String photo, String profession, String education, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.sexualOrientation = sexualOrientation;
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
        this.province = province;
        this.city = city;
        this.selfDescription = selfDescription;
        this.lifeMotto = lifeMotto;
        this.thoughtOfTheDay = thoughtOfTheDay;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.education = education;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public String getSexualOrientation() {
        return sexualOrientation;
    }

    public void setSexualOrientation(String sexualOrientation) {
        this.sexualOrientation = sexualOrientation;
    }

    public String getMaritalStatus() {
        return maritalStatus;
    }

    public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getSelfDescription() {
        return selfDescription;
    }

    public void setSelfDescription(String selfDescription) {
        this.selfDescription = selfDescription;
    }

    public String getLifeMotto() {
        return lifeMotto;
    }

    public void setLifeMotto(String lifeMotto) {
        this.lifeMotto = lifeMotto;
    }

    public String getThoughtOfTheDay() {
        return thoughtOfTheDay;
    }

    public void setThoughtOfTheDay(String thoughtOfTheDay) {
        this.thoughtOfTheDay = thoughtOfTheDay;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }

    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Interest> getInterests() {
        return interests;
    }

    public void addInterest(Interest interest) {
        interests.add(interest);
        interest.getPersons().add(this);
    }

    public void removeInterest(Interest interest) {
        interests.remove(interest);
        interest.getPersons().remove(this);
    }


    public List<Proposition> getPropositions() {
        return propositions;
    }



    public void addProposition(Proposition proposition) {
        if (!this.propositions.contains(proposition)) {
            this.propositions.add(proposition);
            proposition.setPerson(this);
        }
    }

    public void addEmail(Email email) {
        if (!this.emails.contains(email)) {
            this.emails.add(email);
            email.setSender(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeProposition(Proposition proposition) {
        if (this.propositions.contains(proposition)) {
            this.propositions.remove(proposition);
            proposition.setPerson(null);
        }
    }

    public void removeEmail(Email email) {
        if (this.emails.contains(email)) {
            this.emails.remove(email);
            email.setSender(null);
        }
    }

    public void setSecretData(SecretData secretData) {
        this.secretData = secretData;
    }
    public SecretData getSecretData() {
        return secretData;
    }


    public Preference getPreference() {
        return preference;
    }

    public void setPreference(Preference preference) {
        preference.setPerson(this);
        this.preference = preference;

    }

    public void setPropositions(List<Proposition> propositions) {
        this.propositions = propositions;
    }

    public void setInterests(List<Interest> interests) {
        this.interests = interests;
    }

    public List<Email> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }

    public void setEmails(List<Email> emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth +
                ", sex='" + sex + '\'' +
                ", sexualOrientation='" + sexualOrientation + '\'' +
                ", maritalStatus='" + maritalStatus + '\'' +
                ", province='" + province + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", selfDescription='" + selfDescription + '\'' +
                ", lifeMotto='" + lifeMotto + '\'' +
                ", thoughtOfTheDay='" + thoughtOfTheDay + '\'' +
                ", photo='" + photo + '\'' +
                ", profession='" + profession + '\'' +
                ", education='" + education + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", secretData=" + secretData +
                ", preference=" + preference +
                ", propositions=" + propositions +
                ", emails=" + emails +
                ", interests=" + interests +
                '}';
    }



}
```

When I am using Postman/Angular to get the data via REST

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity <List<SecretData>> getAllSecretData(){
        List<SecretData> secretDataList = secretDataService.findAllSecretData();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(secretDataList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Service**

```
public List<SecretData> findAllSecretData(){
        return secretDataRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I am not getting the Person object inside SecredData in JSON.
How can I include this data to sended response? (an object inside second object).
I am trying to use now DTO, but without DTO it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class that should represent the output format you need in your response.

The ***SecretDataOutput*** class that represents the output format

```
public class SecretDataOutput {
  private long id;
  private String login, password, role, privateEmail;

  private Person person;

  public SecretDataOutput(long id, String login, String password, String role, String privateEmail, Person person) {
    this.id = id;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
    this.privateEmail = privateEmail;
    this.person = person;
  }
//getters and setters
```

Use this method to fetch all secrets in your controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/allSecrets")
  public ResponseEntity<List<SecretDataOutput>> getAllSecretData() {
    Iterable<SecretData> allSecretData = service.findAllSecretData();
    List<SecretDataOutput> secretDataOutputList = new ArrayList<>();

    allSecretData.forEach(secretData -> {
      long id = secretData.getId();
      String login = secretData.getLogin();
      String password = secretData.getPassword();
      String privateEmail = secretData.getPrivateEmail();
      String role = secretData.getRole();
      Person person = secretData.getPerson();
      SecretDataOutput secretDataOutput = new SecretDataOutput(id, login, password, role, privateEmail, person);
      secretDataOutputList.add(secretDataOutput);
    });

    return new ResponseEntity<>(secretDataOutputList, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Also, I am expecting when saving a `Person` to a `SecretData` , you are doing a bi-directional mapping:

```
  @GetMapping("/addSecret")
  public String storeSecretData() {
    Person p = new Person("pname", "pLastName", new Date(), "male", "pOrientation", "unmarried", "pProvince", "pCity", "pSelfDesc",
        "pLifeMotto", "pThought", "pPhoto", "pProfession", "pEducation", "pEmail");
    SecretData data = new SecretData("secretLogin", "secretPassword", "secretRole", "secretPrivateEmail");//use this constructor and not the one with the extra Person parameter
    data.addPerson(p); //new method to be added in SecretData class
    try {
      service.saveSecret(data);
      return "Saved";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "Failed";
    }
  }
```

Add this method to your `SecretData` class :

```
  public void addPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
    person.setSecretData(this);
  }
```

This [image] will  be the output in Postman